# Force IE to send URLs in UTF-8

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, default

I am having one issue with the behavior of Internet Explorer and UTF-8 characters in URLs. I found that my site fails to complete the request when IE has unchecked `"Send UTF-8 URLs"` in Internet Options.

When I click on a link on my site to open it in a new page, I get a 404 error page. When I open links in the same page (with no target="_blank"), the links work.

Upon tracing packets, I saw that for UTF8 request, it looks something like this:

```
GET /%EB%89%B4%EC%8A%A4/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

For 404 response, the invalid request looks like this:

```
GET /%B4%BA%BD%BA/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

The URL requested is `/뉴스`. The thing is, using [this site](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) I managed to see that the first, working link, is actually "뉴스" encoded in UTF8. The second one is the same string but encoded in system default, which is EUC-KR.

Using [W3C i18n checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checke%20W3%20i18n%20checker) gave me these results:

```
Character encoding      Code
HTTP Content-Type   UTF-8   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Byte order mark (BOM)   No  
Meta tag    UTF-8   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

Language        Code
HTML tag    ko  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ko" xml:lang="ko">
HTTP Content-Language   None found

Text direction      Code
Default direction   LTR (by default)

Class & id names        Code
Non-ascii class or id names None    
Non-NFC class or id names   None

Request headers     Code
Accept-Language en-US en    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1 utf-8 *  Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

SO, the issue I have now is when opening links in new tabs, **IE encodes the URL in system default encoding,** which breaks the site. I am looking for a solution for this, **how to make the IE send those URLs as UTF8**, for users that have that option turned off? Is there some meta tag I can add to do this, or I have to do some sort of JS modification to parse all of the URLs or some other solution?

I searched extensively for this online and found a lot of resources about UTF8, but none solution to this situation I have which involves IE reverting to system default encoding.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your links, your URL is illegal in HTML4 browsers which then try to fix it by doing random things.

So `<a href="/öäöä"></a>` is invalid in HTML4, but `<a href="/%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4"></a>` is valid and works.

Comment: I already added .encode('utf-8') to my outside links, but still these issues with IE remain. I would like the characters to actually appear in the URL, not the % signs as users would be lost.

This is all working as expected in all other browsers and IE versions with that option checked.

Another thing is that IE sometimes manages to make the correct request even with the option unchecked, what makes it use UTF8 then?

Comment: @wont_compile I don't mean `.encode("utf-8")` I mean URL encoding, there must be percent escaping for all invalid url characters in the html source for `href` attributes. I don't know why it sometimes uses UTF-8 - that's the randomness I am talking about for invalid input. HTML is very forgiving so instead of errors, you get random results.

Comment: In Chrome, when I view source, the links are showing korean chars, but when I copy them to notepad and see them in plain text, they indeed are % encoded. In IE, they appear the same, as Korean, but when copied, they remain Korean. So, IE doesn't encode them as that, Chrome does.

Does this mean that Chrome encodes them, or they are that way sent form the server, but IE renders them as Korean?

I mentioned .encode since I do that on permalinks, where the links are output, so I thought that would kinda cover it and make them "safe" to use in website which has UTF8 charset declared.

Comment: @wont_compile chrome is html5

Comment: What about IE10? Same happens there as well.

Comment: @wont_compile then there is no IRI support or it's violating the spec, the IRI is specified to use UTF-8 when converting from IRI To URI. You can avoid this just by using valid URIs. The percents only show for IE users (dunno about IE10)